# PdfSweep 4.0.1 partial redaction of found string

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, redaction

I've been working on a pdf redaction tool and found this very slick code.  It does nearly everything which is needed and so quickly.

The trouble is I need to redact all but the last four or the found string.  I have tinkered w/custom cleanup strategy, the autocleanup, etc.. I'm missing something.

What are some options to use the following, and redact only a portion of the found text?

Thanks in advance for your input,

```
`try (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(new_File(SRC, "redact")))) 
{
            final ICleanupStrategy cleanupStrategy = new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy(Pattern.compile("Alice", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)).setRedactionColor(ColorConstants.PINK);
            PdfCleaner.autoSweepCleanUp(pdf, cleanupStrategy);
}`
```

I have tinkered w/custom cleanup strategy, the autocleanup, etc.. I'm missing something.  I've reviewed documentation here, unable to connect all the dots:

https://api.itextpdf.com/pdfSweep/dotnet/latest/

Comment: that example you copied from the product page uses a regular expression strategy, albeit a simple one. If you have a pattern you can use to match what you want to redact, why not use that?

Comment: I've updated my regex and the code works well.  I believe I need to get to the underlying calls or write my own strategies.. just haven't found enough info to jump start me.  My mods should work like this:

1.  Search PDF for anything resembling a credit card/account number (>= 15 chars)
2.  Redact the same EXCEPT the last 4 of the found number string.  

Here's where it gets tricky.  You know the long string of numbers typically at bottom of the first page of your statement.  in the number string is your account number.  I am redacting the full string.. goal to expose the last 4 chars

Comment: You have to search for required string (16 characters CC number), the search results must include positions for each character. Compute the bounding rectangle for first 12 characters and then redact that rectangle.